# Javascript return property instead of object during object initialization

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns

is there way to change, what object actual is, when we manipulate with it?
For exaple, if I have this class:

```
class Parent{
    child;
    contructor(){
        child = new Child();
    }
}
class Child{
    sayHello(){
        console.log("Hello");
    }
}
```

When I create instance of Parent class, I want to manipulate directly with its child property (which is actually reference to another object).
I want to be able to do this:

```
let myObj = new Parent();
myObj.sayHello()
```

Sorry for silly/poor explanation, I really don't know right terminology for this.

Is there way to do what I want? Or any solution which give "similar" result to what I want?
Notice, that what I really don't want is to solve it something like this:

```
let myObj = new Parent();
myObj.child.sayHello()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want this? Sounds like an X Y problem

Comment: `child;` is not (yet) valid syntax in a `class` declaration, and instead of `child = …;` you meant to do `this.child = …;`?

Answer (score 0):

You *could* define a proxy method on `Parent` that will call the child method, like so:

```js
class Parent {
    constructor() {
        this.child = new Child();
    }

    sayHello() {
        this.child.sayHello();
    }
}

class Child {
    sayHello() {
        console.log("Hello");
    }
}
```

However this might not be the correct abstraction. Could you explain *why* you want to do this, and why the example you've given (`parent.child.method()`) won't work for you?

For example, maybe depending on your use case, a factory method is more appropriate? Eg.

```js
class ChildFactory {
  static makeChild() {
      const child = new Child();
      return child;
  }
}

class Child {
  sayHello() {
      console.log("Hello");
  }
}

const myChild = ChildFactory.makeChild();
myChild.sayHello();
```

Comment: Agreed. That's why I asked OP why they want to do this. Without context it's hard to know what they want to do exactly. The ideal solution would be just to instantiate `Child` directly, but I guess there is some reason OP can't do that.